# EJB,JPA persistance.xml problem Wildfly 8.2 intellij

Tags: java, jboss

I'am using intellij Idea to create an EJB with JPA and Jboss 8.2 :
i am building a jar file as output when i uncompress the jar file persistance.xml is not found in meta-info folder, and when i run there server it gives me an exception unit name not found .
is there a solution and thanx a lot .

this persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="EJBUser" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/EJBUser</jta-data-source>
        <class>entities.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

this is my bean

```
package ejb;

import bl.UserLocal;
import entities.User;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
 * Created by mehdi on 04/02/2019.
 */
@Stateless(name = "UserImpLocalEJB")
public class UserImpLocalBean implements UserLocal{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EJBUser")
    private EntityManager em;
    public UserImpLocalBean() {
    }

    @Override
    public User addUser(User user) {
        em.persist(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

and finally this is the exception ;

```
20:10:40,122 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011047: Component class ejb.UserImpLocalBean for component UserImpLocalEJB has errors: 
JBAS011440: Can't find a persistence unit named EJBUser in deployment "EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.handle(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:159)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.processClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:152)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:145)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more

20:10:40,133 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar")]) - failure description: {
    "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011047: Component class ejb.UserImpLocalBean for component UserImpLocalEJB has errors: 
JBAS011440: Can't find a persistence unit named EJBUser in deployment \"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\""},
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB]"
    ]
}
20:10:40,137 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011047: Component class ejb.UserImpLocalBean for component UserImpLocalEJB has errors: 
JBAS011440: Can't find a persistence unit named EJBUser in deployment \"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\""},
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB]"
    ]
}
20:10:40,150 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar (runtime-name: EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar) in 13ms
20:10:40,152 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar".weld.weldClassIntrospector] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."EJBUser_ejb exploded"."EJBUser_ejb exploded".UserImpLocalEJB (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."EJBUser_ejb exploded"."EJBUser_ejb exploded".UserImpLocalEJB.InstanceName, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."EJBUser_ejb exploded"."EJBUser_ejb exploded".UserImpLocalEJB.Validator, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."EJBUser_ejb exploded"."EJBUser_ejb exploded".UserImpLocalEJB.InAppClientContainer, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."EJBUser_ejb exploded"."EJBUser_ejb exploded".UserImpLocalEJB.ValidatorFactory] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar".INSTALL

[2019-02-04 08:10:40,229] Artifact EJBUser:ejb exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2019-02-04 08:10:40,250] Artifact EJBUser:ejb exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011047: Component class ejb.UserImpLocalBean for component UserImpLocalEJB has errors: 
JBAS011440: Can't find a persistence unit named EJBUser in deployment \"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\""},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded.jar\".beanmanager]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".\"EJBUser_ejb exploded\".UserImpLocalEJB]"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have already figured out from the error log, Wildfly is complaining that it is unable to find a persistence context in the EJB because the persistence.xml file is missing in the JAR. it must be kept at the root level in a META-INF directory.

**If you want IntelliJ to automatically package it in a META-INF directory in your JAR, `META-INF/persistence.xml` should be under source root in IntelliJ**.

Comment: Could be that the Maven plugin didn't create the appropriate EAR.  Check the EAR and see if you need to amend the build plugin in your pom.xml

Comment: Sir yes it is but in the building it is not added to jar archive.

Comment: @MehdiGasserini, like I highlighted in bold, you need to keep the META-INF folder with the persistence.xml under source root in intellij for it to package it in your JAR.

Comment: thanx sir a lot the problem was not there . it was in project building structure

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by adding a JPA descriptor from project structure 
[the image describe how to add it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvFFk.png)